# JavaScript outputs junk text

Tags: javascript

I am following a tutorial to learn JavaScript. The simple image scrolling script works but mine also outputs a lode of junk text, the example does not. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my JavaScript syntax?

The junk text looks like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}} {\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sl240\slmult1\lang9\f0\fs22 \par \par \tab \par \par \par \par \tab \par \par \par }
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="imgscroll.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="1.jpg" id="scroll" />
</body>
</html>
```

imgscroll.js

```
window.onload = rotate;

var images = new Array("1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg");
var thisImg = 0;

function rotate() {
    thisImg++;
    if (thisImg == images.length) {
        thisImg = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("scroll").src = images[thisImg];
    setTimeout("rotate()", 3 * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Add an opening html tag
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is saved in RTF (Rich text format). Write it in notepad with no formatting, and it should work. Also, you might want to add an opening html tag (`<html>`) after `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Thanks, that worked, using jedit now instead of wordpad, a much better editor

Comment: @chewdonkey this problem happened to me as well. fairly easy fix, but just make sure you use a basic no-format editor in future. glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one of your images is a word document with changed extension... Do a check on your files.